# MySQL CSV import permission denied

Tags: mysql

Similar problems have been discussed many times, but I found no solution working in my case.

Mysql version :

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.30, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

On Ubuntu 15.10 64 bits desktop.

Here is the command i try to run :

```
$ mysql -u dmeziere -p -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/FR.csv' INTO TABLE project_dev.cities CHARACTER SET 'UTF8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 0 ROWS (country_code, country_name, postal_code, place_name, admin_name1, admin_code1, admin_name2, admin_code2, admin_name3, admin_code3, latitude, longitude, accuracy);"
Enter password: 
ERROR 29 (HY000) at line 1: File '/tmp/FR.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

As you see, client and server are on the same host.

This command is a copy/paste of the one I usualy run on the same schema, on another server (MySQL 5.5.43 on Debian 8.0).

Trying "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" is refused. adding --local-infile doesn't work.

Here are my grants :

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dmeziere@localhost                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dmeziere'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '***' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

So I should have the FILE privilege. Anyway, i also tryed with the mysql root default account.

Here are the file perms :

```
$ ll /tmp/FR.csv 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dmeziere dmeziere 6,2M mai   25 13:08 /tmp/FR.csv
```

So the file exists and is accessible. As you imagine, I tried to move the file from a deeper path to limit errors, and gave it full permissions while trying to find clues. Perms on /tmp are drwxrwxrwt root root. I also tryed to sudo mysql.

Neither systems use SE Linux.

At last, I SELECTed * on the table to ensure it was still empty, to eliminate a false negative bug.

An idea ?

Comment: Store file in mysql bin directory and give that file path in above query.
It should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally it wasn't a filesystem problem. It is MySQL that refused to read the CSV file, no matter the privileges. Putting the CSV file in MySQL data directory (usually /var/lib/mysql) did he job. This security feature doesn't seems to be present on every flavours of MySQL and OSes.

Of course you shouldn't forget to remove the file after import.

I find this behaviour a bit curious. I don't really understand why importing a CSV file should be harder than importing a DQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
service apparmor stop
service apparmor teardown
```

I've encountered the same issue and fixed it by these commands.